# Validate user entered weblogic location

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

Is there any standard way to check if the value entered by user for weblogic location is correct or not? Basically, the application that I'm developing requires user to enter the weblogic location. I would like to check if the path entered by user is correct and also display the version of weblogic detected.

Comment: What do you mean by WebLogic location? I don' t believe it's a standard term...

Answer (score 0):

I have installed my weblogic at

```
/home/oracle/Middleware/
```

I can get the version using the directory:

```
/home/oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/
```

And, I can make sure about the installed weblogic by locating the jar:

```
/home/oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The program probably uses its name in its files, so the below command will show it.

```
whereis weblogic
```

If the program came as a package, try

```
for .deb: dpkg -l | grep weblogic
for .rpm: rpm -q weblogic
```